# Tap to start Image

Tags: ios, iphone, flappy-bird-clone

Hello I am trying to add a tap to start image like the one in flappy birds but I cant really find what I'm looking for on the webs so I came here. I have tried using UIImageView to do this but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: did you tried using `UIButton` ?

Comment: No but do you know how I would do this ?

Comment: i know but i am here to help , not write your code for you

Comment: I know i am asking for suggestions on where to find a tutorial on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this task this way. When you add image  add a transparent button over imageView and then from the button's action start the activity.

Code for transparent button

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the UIImageView and set the UIImageView's userInteractionEnabled to YES.

Try this

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewTapped)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[tapGesture release];
```

and implement this

```
- (void)viewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UIView *tappedView = gestureRecognizer.view;
}
```